# Weird behavior while using gevent Greenlets

Tags: python, python-3.x, gevent, greenlets

I am new to async programming. I am doing a small POC where I want to see how `greenlets` behave with shared objects. I have written this code -

```
from gevent import monkey, sleep
from gevent import Greenlet
monkey.patch_all(thread=False, socket=False)

class Events:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 0
        self.limit = 10
        self.bulk_records = []

    def start(self, task_number=0):
        count = 0
        print("Task: %s started" % task_number)
        while count != 10:
            self.bulk_records.append(task_number)
            sleep(0.1)
            if len(self.bulk_records) == self.limit:
                print("%s, Task %s, outputting list: %s" % (self.num, task_number, self.bulk_records))
                self.bulk_records[:] = []
                self.num += 1
            count += 1
        print("Task - %s, count - %s" % (task_number, count))

def run_test():
    event = Events()
    tasks = [Greenlet.spawn(event.start, i) for i in range(5)]
    print("Num tasks - %s" % len(tasks))
    [task.run() for task in tasks]
    print("End")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_test()
```

It gives the following output:-

```
Num tasks - 5
Task: 0 started
Task: 1 started
Task: 2 started
Task: 3 started
Task: 4 started
0, Task 0, outputting list: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
1, Task 0, outputting list: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
2, Task 0, outputting list: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
3, Task 0, outputting list: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
4, Task 0, outputting list: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
Task - 0, count - 10
Task: 1 started # This is not expected
Task - 1, count - 10
Task - 2, count - 10
Task - 3, count - 10
Task - 4, count - 10
5, Task 1, outputting list: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
Task - 1, count - 10
End

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The code works as expected but in the end something weird happened, Task 1 is started again and the corresponding function `start` is executed again.

Not sure if this is a valid behavior, or what I am missing in the code to prevent `Greenlet` to start again.

Thanks is advance

Comment: Had a quick look, I don't have any explanation except that this might be a bug in greenlet/gevent... It seems unlikely such a bug wouldn't have been discovered though? What version of Python are you using? Is it also your understanding that the greenlets yield on the calls to `print`?

Comment: this call ` [task.run() for task in tasks]` is wrong ; what is it for? `spawn` already runs greenlets. You want to wait until execution of greenlets is done using `gevent.joinall(tasks)`. Do not call 'run' directly.

Comment: Hello @mguijarr, kindly post this as an answer and I will accept this. The solution provided by you works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to the thread API, which requires a thread object to be created and to call the `start()` method, `gevent.spawn` does both greenlet instantiation and schedules the greenlet to run in one call.

So, calling `run()` on greenlet objects is not needed (and probably very wrong in most cases).

Waiting for tasks to be completed is done with `joinall(list of greenlets)`. After this call, all greenlets are ready (dead, successfully or not).